# GIT Embedded with Web Application Server

Tags: java, git, version-control, application-server

I would like to know that Is it possible to embed GIT repositories with a web application server?
When the server start up, repository will be up and if down; will be down.

Or, Can I add git repo with a perticular web application?

and How can I read a file from GIT repositories through JAVA API.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read file from git through Java API, you can use jgit.

I find this page is quite good.
http://www.doublecloud.org/2013/01/how-to-read-git-repository-using-java-apis/

To make the availability of your git server following the status of your web server, i think it's just a matter of startup/shutdown script configuration of your web server script.

Comment: I have already gone through the same and connecting to the git repository by the code provided. BTW, GIT server is git repository either in local or remorte? How can I set up remote git hub server?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For read a file content try [scm4j-vcs-git](https://github.com/scm4j/scm4j-vcs-git):

```
 public static final String WORKSPACE_DIR = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir") + "git-workspaces";
 IVCSWorkspace workspace = new VCSWorkspace(WORKSPACE_DIR);
 String repoUrl = "https://github.com/MyUser/MyRepo";
 IVCSRepositoryWorkspace repoWorkspace = workspace.getVCSRepositoryWorkspace(repoUrl);
 IVCS vcs = new GitVCS(repoWorkspace);
 vcs.setCredentials("user", "password"); // if necessary
 String branchName = "my-branch"; // or null for master
 String revision = "commit-sha1"; // or null for branch HEAD
 String fileContent = vcs.getFileContent(branchName , "folder/file.txt", revision);
```